# Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

//this code,what i have and near "ON" i can not see incorrect syntax

```
CREATE DATABASE ShopDB
ON
(
NAME = 'ShopDB',
FILENAME = 'C:\Projects\SQL\ShopDB.mdf',
SIZE = 10MB,
MAXSIZE = 100MB,
FILEGROWTH = 10MB
)
LOG ON
(
NAME = 'LogShopDB',
FILENAME = 'C:\Projects\SQL\ShopDB.ldf',
SIZE = 5MB,
MAXSIZE = 50MB,
FILEGROWTH = 5MB
)
```

Comment: Worked for me. What version of SQL Server are you using? Are you sure the folders exists?

Comment: Can you show the exact error message?

Comment: Try with 'N' before filename path

e.g. FILENAME = N'C:\Projects\SQL\ShopDB.mdf',

Comment: In sql server its working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  Database [ShopDB]    Script Date: 7/27/2017 5:42:58 PM ******/
CREATE DATABASE [ShopDB]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'ShopDB', 
    FILENAME = N'D:\SqlDatabseFiles\ShopDB.mdf' , 
    SIZE = 4096KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED,
    FILEGROWTH = 1024KB 
)
 LOG ON 
(    NAME = N'ShopDB_log', 
     FILENAME = N'D:\SqlDatabseFiles\ShopDB_log.ldf' , 
     SIZE = 1024KB , 
     MAXSIZE = 2048GB ,
     FILEGROWTH = 10%
)
GO
```

Comment: Thank's a lot. I coped this code, deleted this project, created new and pasted this code/ and all was working. But If I have the same problem - I'll try your way.